# Big O and Big Omega Proof with lg base 2

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Hello I am a beginner to this kind of notation and I would greatly appreciate an explanation which is easy to understand.

I need to prove

$$ \log_2(6 + \frac1x) = O(1) $$

and

$$ \log_2(6 + \frac1x) = \Omega(1) $$

My first thought would be to combine the equation inside, then separate the logs based on the division rule. But I tried, and I do not know what to do after that, or if that is the correct way.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hint: what is the definition of $O$ and $\Omega$?

Comment: As an "intuitive" justification, realize that, as $x$ gets really big, $1/x$ is quite small.  Thus, $6+1/x$ can be bounded above (and below) by some constant.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that
you are letting
$x \to \infty$.
From this,
we can certainly assume that
$x > 1$.

For the first equation,
from the definition of
"big-oh",
we want to show that
there is a postive $c$
such that
$\log_2(6 + \frac1x) < c$
for all $x > \text{ some }b$.
If $x > b$,
then
$\frac1{x} < 1/b$,
so
$\log_2(6 + \frac1x) 
< \log_2(6 + \frac1 b) 
$
and we can choose this vale for $c$.

Doing some cut, paste, and edit:

For the second equation,
from the definition of
"big-omega",
we want to show that
there is a postive $c$
such that
$\log_2(6 + \frac1x) > c$
for all $x > \text{ some }b$.
If $x > b$,
then
$\frac1{x} > 0$,
so
$\log_2(6 + \frac1x) 
> \log_2(6) 
$
and we can choose this value for $c$.

Comment: So simple! thank you ^_^